# Generate GUID with POST Request - Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, ionic-framework

I need to generate GUIDs when users submit a POST request. I have never worked with GUIDs before so it would be great if someone can help me here. These are the codes I have for now

for the GUIDs

```
constructor(public http: HttpClient ) {

class Guid {
  static newGuid() {
      return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
          var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
          return v.toString(16);
      });
  }
}

// Example of a bunch of GUIDs
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var id = Guid.newGuid();
    console.log(id);
}}
```

API that I need to generate GUID for:

```
updateSpin(spin_result_id: AAGUID, inventory_id: AAGUID, status: string){
return Observable.create(observer => {
  this.http.post(`${this.dataApiUrl}//some api`,
    {records: [{
      "inventory_id": inventory_id,
      "status": status
    }],
    resource_id: '//some api'},
    {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN')),
    responseType: 'text'})
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    observer.next(true);
    observer.complete(true);
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
    observer.next(false);
    observer.complete();
  })
});}
```

I have tried searching online but I don't really understand how I can implement GUIDs into my current codes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [Github gist](https://gist.github.com/LeverOne/1308368):

```
const uuid = function(a,b){for(b=a='';a++<36;b+=a*51&52?(a^15?8^Math.random()*(a^20?16:4):4).toString(16):'-');return b};
// usage
const id = uuid();
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to SO. :)

Answer (score 2):

Test this function:

```
public static generateGUID() {
    function S4() {
        return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) || 0).toString(16).substring(1);
    }

    return (S4() + S4());
}

console.log(generateGUID());
```

I hope my help is effective ツ

Comment: Are you sure? My console results in something like `bb7e.b026266a27d1.84136aebc` which is definitely not a GUID format